# Error compilation with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
enum class Order : char
{
    Little,
    Big
};

constexpr Order get_order() {
    uint16_t x = 1;
    return *((uint8_t *) &x) == 0 ? Order::Big : Order::Little;
}
```

I do it with `-std=c++14` flag but i get that error:

> In function ‘constexpr byteorder::Order byteorder::get_order()’:
>   /home/user/dev/c++/render/include/byteorder.h:19:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr byteorder::Order byteorder::get_order()’ not a return-statement

*It looks like c++11 !*

How could it happen if c++14 allows local variables in constexpr functions?

Debian Jessie, gcc 4.9.2

Comment: I dont get the error [here](http://ideone.com/K3Mv2K), or [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8152eed3cd601f01) are you sure the command line is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GCC [standard implementation page here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14) it looks like this is only available in GCC version 5 and above.

It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4712140e90b26d71) using [GCC 6.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7563a647a81f30b5).

Comment: It may "work" but it is illegal as specified by [\[exp.const\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2)

Comment: @NathanOliver Just so i am checking the right thing, is it [exp.const]/2 clause: `a reinterpret_cast ([expr.reinterpret.cast]);` that you think it violates?

Comment: @Ben Yes.  A `reinterpret_cast` makes it not a *core constant expression*

Comment: @NathanOliver But i cant see anything under [[expr.reinterpret.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)] that makes `(uint8_t *) &x` a `reinterpret_cast` expression. Doesn't it need to actually be a `reinterpret_cast` call to be considered as such?

Comment: @Ben The standard states *following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following expressions* and I believe `*((uint8_t *) &x)` would evaluate to a `reinterpret_cast`.  Maybe that is a heavy handed approach but I believe it is valid as it is non-portable and `constexpr` should be portable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you give me an idea of the subsection of [intro.execution] that you think would indicate evaluation occurs this way?

Answer (score 6):

clang says:

```
test.cpp:9:17: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression
    [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr Order get_order() {
                ^
test.cpp:11:14: note: cast that performs the conversions of a reinterpret_cast
is not allowed in a constant expression
    return *((uint8_t *) &x) == 0 ? Order::Big : Order::Little;
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.

You're taking the address of a local variable(assigned on runtime) and that mean there's no possible to evaluate that expression at compile time.

**EDIT:**
Despite the above said, expressions that may cause undefined behavior are considered restricted from core constant expressions and function where it appears fail to meet the `constexpr` requirements. pointer dereference may fall under this category or casting using `reinterpret_cast` which is like the same as traditional casting.

Comment: So then it might to be evaluated at runtime, right?

Comment: The point is that compile and execution are disjoint phases, that said, constexpr need to be evaluated at compile time which result when pointers are involved need to be by [expr.const]/5  "the address of an object with static storage duration, the address of a function, or a null pointer value."  and what you're doing is taking and address of a local variable through cast, which not result in a core constant value.